# Is it possible to change the default text cursor orientation from vertical to horizontal?

Tags: windows-7, windows, text-editing, text-cursor

In almost any application or Windows component, the text cursor usually appears as a vertical black line -- in Notepad, browser address bar, the Run window.

Is there a setting I can tweak in the Windows registry to change it to a horizontal cursor, similar to what Ommwriter (see below) or the command prompt has?

[image: How the text cursor appears in Ommwriter]
[image]

Comment: that's a groundbreaking idea, it could take a decade to develop

Comment: I suppose it's application-specific. I did find [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648398(v=VS.85).aspx#_win32_Creating_and_Displaying_a_Caret) & [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938231.aspx)

Comment: How about this http://www.thebitguru.com/articles/14-Programmatically+Changing+Windows+Mouse+Cursors

Comment: "that's a groundbreaking idea, it could take a decade to develop"  was a joke.  From a programmer's perspective it is no doubt very simple. And congratulations you found an example of that.   The specific concept itself is not going to revolutionise computing, it's an incredibly simple concept, but one that is almost impossible if MS didn't happen to put a way in to do it. And so in theory, it could take a decade or a hundred years. The joke being the suggestion of programmers working on this changing the cursor in notepad, for a decade, the point that we might never get there.

Comment: Someone already posted a similar link as an answer but he/she removed it. Again that's for the mouse cursor, not the caret. And yes, I know sarcasm too. Ty for explaining your "joke" though.

Comment: Ah you're right.. i just went to start..ctrl panel..mouse..found what looked like position cursor..saw a browse option clicked browse changed it to a banana icon.. went to notepad and lo and behold,  it didn't do it..was just the mouse cursor.. and I see that article was just about automating that..darn.

Comment: I'm sure you're a smart person. I would appreciate it if you could provide educated responses. A simple "no, i don't think what you want to do is possible, atm" would have sufficed.

Comment: As for your link, I appreciate the gesture, but if you would kindly review my question, you'll see that it's not about the mouse cursor or automating its customization.

Comment: I can see that. I assure you, if somebody knows, they'll answer.

Comment: Please keep comments civil and relevant to the question, or else they will be deleted.

Comment: If no well known hack,then the people that'd know are more likely to be programmers e.g. on stackoverflow,so you may be able  to rephrase the question to one that asks them, whether programs making that positional cursor are calling a common windows function.Or whether they implement it themselves.And explain that the point,is your want to know if it's even possible -in theory- to change/hack/replace/overwrite the procedure within windows. 'cos doing so would affect many applications whose code you cannot access. It's a longshot, and it's something programmers would know more than techies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Hidden Koala the insert key will change the cursor orientation as you are wanting (usually), but probably you don't want it in insert mode. However it points out the possibility of changing things. Perhaps explore key remapping. If the insert key can change it to a horizontal orientation, checking that default mapping may get you where you want.